# gnuplot, plot rotation arrows

Tags: gnuplot

Recently I have been using gnuplot to plot position data over time. In my datafile, I have time,positional (2D) information, and directional information (in the form of degrees, 0-360). I have nice plots of position wrt to time, however, I was wondering if it's possible to plot degrees as a rotation of individual plot characters. Does anyone have any suggestions for a way to do this?

here is the example script that I am plotting. In this plot there are three files, and 3 data sets. Each containing position and time information, and representing data from a different antenna type. columns 3 and 2 contain position information, and column 1 contains time information.

`gnuplot> plot 'gpsfile1.txt' using 3:2:1 ls 1 lc palette title 'smallant', 'gpsfile2.txt'
 using 6:5:4 ls 5 lc palette title 'FullWave', 'ant_lady_dog_clouds.txt' using 9:8:7 ls 7 lc palette title 'control'`

plotted, this data looks like this

[image: 2d position data over time time]

I have a 4th column that represents orientation from magnetic north. I would like to know if there is a good way to display this 4th dimension, preferably by rotating the markers.
Any thoughts?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) or a screenshot that illustrates your problem. As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again until you get more rep points.

Answer (score 2):

## Remarks

I'm not sure if I got you right. If you want to annotate your points with an additional orientation use the `using vectors` style.

## Implementation

Because this is TeX.SX, the solution incorporates the `epslatex` terminal `:-)`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

reset
set terminal epslatex color standalone
set output 'gnuplot.tex'

set angles degrees
set xrange [0:3]
set yrange [0:4]

plot '-' using 1:2:(0.2*cos($4)):(0.2*sin($4)):3 with vectors linecolor palette notitle
# x y color angle
  1 1 5     30
  2 1 4     40
  2 3 3     45
  1 2 3     60
  2 2 4     160
  1 3 3     80
```

## Output

> [image]